# Reading, translating and writing data between multiple CSV files using C

Tags: c, file, csv, scanf

I have 3 CSV files. The first of them contains 4 columns:

```
ID,Section1,Section2,Secion3
1,23,12,7
2,11,26,9
. . . .
. . . .
19,30,22,4
20,5,6,16
```

The first column is the ID and the other three contain random numbers ranging from 0 to 30.
The next file is a "conversion" file. It shows the corresponding value to each number:

```
30,45,44,45
29,44,42,43
28,43,42,41
. . . .
. . . .
1,22,21,22
0,20,21,21
```

The first column is the number to be read and the next columns are the values that will replace those numbers in each Section.
Like, if you read a 30 in Section1 it will be replaced by a 45, and if you find a 29 in Section 2 it will be replaced by a 42 and so on.
If I were to write the converted numbers into a third CSV file with the same 4 column format, how should I do it?
So far I've had no problems with generating the files since they are randomized, except for the "conversion" file, but I don't know how to proceed with the conversion.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc,char *argv[]){
    int i, num1;
    char numbers[20][20];
    char conversions[20][20];

    //File with the initial numbers
    FILE *registry = fopen("registry.csv","w+");
    if (registry == NULL){
        fputs ("File error",stderr); 
        exit (1);
    }
    //Conversion file
    FILE *conversion = fopen("conversion.csv","r");
    if (conversion == NULL){
        fputs ("File error",stderr); 
        exit (1);
    }
    //File where the resulting values will be written
    FILE *results = fopen("results.csv","a");
    if (results == NULL){
        fputs ("File error",stderr); 
        exit (1);
    }

    //Writing the headers
    fprintf(results,"ID,Results1,Results2,Results3\n");
    fprintf(registry,"ID,Section1,Section2,Section3\n");
    srand(time(0));

    //Generating the random numbers
    for(i=1;i<21;i++){
        sprintf(numbers[i],"%d,%d,%d,%d\n",i,rand()%31,rand()%31,
            rand()%31);
        fputs(numbers[i], registry);
    }

    //This is where I don't know how to proceed

    for(i=1;i<21;i++){
        sprintf(conversions[i],"%d,%d,%d,%d\n",i,
            fscanf(registry,"%d,%*s,%*s,%*s\n",num1)...);


    }
```

I was trying to do something like what I did to generate the random numbers by saving everything into a buffer and then writing it into the file and I found that the fscanf function can be of great use to skip the parts I don't need to read, but I couldn't figure out how to use it to skip the headers and the ID column and I'm still missing the conversion part.
Conversion file:

```
30,45,44,45
29,44,43,43
28,43,42,42
27,43,41,40
26,41,40,40
25,40,39,39
24,39,37,39
23,38,37,38
22,38,36,37
21,36,36,37
20,35,35,36
19,34,34,35
18,33,34,35
17,33,33,34
16,32,32,33
15,32,31,32
14,31,30,31
13,30,30,31
12,29,29,30
11,29,28,29
10,28,28,29
9,28,27,27
8,27,26,26
7,27,26,25
6,26,25,25
5,25,24,24
4,25,23,24
3,24,23,23
2,23,22,21
1,21,21,20
0,20,21,20
```

Comment: Is this: `ID,Section1,Section2,Secion3` considered your header?   Will it always be one line?  Are the number of data lines in your input file always the same, or can the count vary from file to file?  Is the number of comma, delimited columns in your data file always the same, or can it vary?

Comment: Yes, ID and sections are the header and it is only one line, the data lines are 20 always and the columns and commas are also the same. It keeps the same format.

Comment: Because they are formed with clear repeatable format, I would be happy to show you how I would read the files in, but I would not want to try to unscramble what it is you are doing with them.  The problem description really needs to be simplified into a [mcve].  If you are interested in that, leave me a comment, and I will look at it tomorrow.  Best!

Comment: Yes, please, it would be of much help.

Comment: In looking at your sample conversion table, is it also populated with random numbers? Or is there some pattern there?  And, why is the left column numbered from 30 to 1 instead of 1 to 30?  In any case, If the table normally  already exists before this code is run, and is created outside your code, then provide its contents in in your post please. (Your code does not include writing the conversion values.)

Comment: The numbers in the conversion table are not random, but there is also no pattern. The order is no important, for the left column. It could be from 30 to 1 or 1 to 30.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the table you provided for testing my code before posting.  Sorry about delay.  I am working on a rushed project at this time.

Comment: The approach I used in my answer should help you get that last part in your question, but also made other suggestions that you can choose to use or not, i.e. such as leaving out anything but data in the three files (no headers, and no first column) This in general make processing data much simpler.  If you need to see line numbers and headers when you read the data, then you are welcome of coarse to adjust the example code in my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is scoped to address:
*`//This is where I don't know how to proceed`*.

To do what you have described, if it is not necessary to include the first columns in  registry, results or conversion for storing, then do not. Although nice for human readability, they complicate the task of reading in, and using arrays.  The unused column data and header row requires array indexing gymnastics to get the data to line up correctly into the arrays.
Without the header row and numbering column, array indexes alone are sufficient to track all that is needed to make the conversion.
*However*, if you feel the first column/row is needed for your purposes, then adjust the array indexing of the routines shown below to accommodate.

The following steps (some of which you already do) are what I identified as essential toward  making the conversion step as simple as possible...

Steps:

- Create registry - 60 - random numbers (0-30) arranged in 20 rows, 3
  data columns
- Create `int reg[20][3] = {{0}};`
- Read registry into reg array using a combination `fgets` `sscanf` routine.

Example:(assuming registry has already been created in your code)

```
registry = fopen(".\\registry.csv","r");
if (registry)
{
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), registry))
    {
        sscanf(buf, "%d,%d,%d", &reg[index][0],&reg[index][1],&reg[index][2] );
        index++;
    }
    fclose(registry);
}
```

conversion table - pre-existing file

- Create `int conv[31][3] = {{0}};`
- Read conversion table into conv array using a combination `fgets` `sscanf`  routine (see above example)

Once you have these arrays created properly,
Perform conversion:

- Create `int res[20][3] = {{0}};`
- Create `char buf[80] = {0};`
- Open 'results' file: `FILE *results = fopen(".\\results.csv","w");`
- populate results:

Example:

```
//File where the resulting values will be written
FILE *results = fopen(".\\results.csv","w");
if (results)
{
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(reg)/sizeof(reg[0]);i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<sizeof(reg[0])/sizeof(reg[0][0]);j++)
        {
            res[i][j] = conv[reg[i][j]][j];
        //      |                         |  |___reg col   == conv col
        //      |                         |______value reg == conv row
        //      |________________________________row and column of conv
        }
        sprintf(buf, "%d,%d,%d\n", res[i][0],res[i][1],res[i][2]);
        fputs(buf, results);

    }
    fclose(results);    
}
```

At this point, you can print the results file in a format that suits your needs.

Following is an image showing actual results using suggested approaches above for a randomly generated `registry`, the values you provided for `conversion` and resulting `results`. (each created without column 1 shown in your original code, as I suggested in my comments.) Image is showing indexing from 0 - n for each set of array data:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been able to issue a proper response. This perfectly solved my problem. Thank you very much for your time and your help.

Comment: @SebastianM. - Glad to help.  Thank you.